# Is Jeff Van Drew becoming a Republican?

Tags: united-states, congress, trump-impeachment

It seems to me that [Jeff Van Drew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Van_Drew) is the only party defector in this impeachment. Is he actually switching parties?

Comment: There were in total two Democrats voting against both articles, one more Democrat voting against one article and in favor of the other, and one Democrat voting "present" (that is: neutral) on both articles.

Comment: And for completeness: the single independent Representative - a former Republican - voted in favor on both articles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Jeff van Drew plans to become a Republican](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/kadiagoba/jeff-van-drew-democrat-republican-switch-parties-impeachment).

Collin Peterson (MN-8) also voted against both articles of impeachment. He has not announced any intention to leave the Democratic party.